# Preference of HTTP Server

Tags: delphi, http

I am trying my hand in server applications using Indy Internet tools.

My client sends Post data (XML) in Unicode format.

Can I convey my preference to client (HTTP Client). I prefer Text. In general can a HTTP server send its preferences to its Clients?

Thanks for any hint or help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is the fact, that with only one `POST` the server has no way to respond, until the client has already sent the data.

The solution is to **make two calls**: One where the client asks for the server preferences and another to send the data. The `OPTIONS` HTTP method can be used for this scenario.

You can handle both requests on the same URL: If the clients makes an `OPTIONS` request the server responds with the configuration data. (via response headers) Then the client can make a `POST` request on the same URL and the server handles the data appropriately.

For further information see [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and [HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), especially the `Accept` header.